# MySQL - Strange behavior in subquery with LIMIT / ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a strange problem :

---

```
select * from (
    select id from myTable1 limit 10
) t1
union
select * from (
    select id from myTable2 limit 10
) t2
```

`=> Return 20 rows`

---

```
select * from (
    select id from myTable1 limit 10 ORDER BY id
) t1
union
select * from (
    select id from myTable2 limit 10
) t2
```

`=> Return 10 rows`

---

As you can see, the only differences between those two queries is the "order by" in the first subquery.

Is it a bug or am I missing something here ?

More infos :

```
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
innodb_version              5.6.16
protocol_version            10
slave_type_conversions  
version                     5.6.16
version_comment             MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine     x86_64
version_compile_os          Win64
```

Comment: Looks like its eliminating the duplicate rows with union while you do order by.. try `union all` instead.

Comment: On the second query it happens that the two sub-queries return the same 10 rows and [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) removes the duplicates. Use `UNION ALL` to keep them. Also, you don't need the outer `SELECT`s; the inner queries together with the parenthesis surrounding them are enough.

Comment: Ids in table1 starts at 10000 and ids in table2 starts at 1, there is not duplicate (I'm gonna try anyway)

Comment: @Apolo . . . It is also possible that you have duplicates *within* each table.  When duplicates are removed, the query happens to find 10 distinct values.

Comment: @axiac RE : Your advice leads me to the solution, I'm posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a simple mistake :

The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` were swapped :

```
(
    select id from myTable1 ORDER BY id limit 10
)
union
(
    select id from myTable2 limit 10
)
```

`=> return 20 rows`

As suggested in comments, it's better to use `UNION ALL` but my 2 data sets have no data in common.

Comment: Nice, I didn't notice the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses were swapped. Shouldn't it trigger an error? It's interesting that `select id from myTable1 limit 10 ORDER BY id` triggers the error but when it is enclosed in `select * from (...) t1` it doesn't trigger the error but it doesn't return any row either :-(